# Elasticsearch not finding JAVA_HOME or Java, even when both of these are existing

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to setup a computer with elasticsearch. However, I am currently encountering a problem when doing so : It seems that elasticsearch can't find my Java installation, even when said installation is here, and working as intended.

Not knowing what the problem might have been, I tried to solve it by changing the Java version, thinking it might be an unsupported one : I tried with jre 1.8.0, jre version 8 update 211, jdk 1.8.0, and jdk 12.0.1. None of these solved my issue, even when rebooting after changing it.
It is worth noting that the version of elasticsearch that I'm required to work with is 6.2.3.

Currently, when I try to execute anything from elasticsearch, I'm greeted with the following output :

```
C:\elasticsearch-6.2.3\bin> elasticsearch
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH
```

[EDIT] Trying to execute elasticsearch in a git bash shows the following output :

```
XXXXXX@PC-76-WIN10 MINGW64 /c/elasticsearch-6.2.3/bin
$ ./elasticsearch
Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JavaVersionChecker
```

This can be translated in english to "Impossible to find or load the class org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JavaVersionChecker".
[END OF EDIT]

However, here are some outputs showing that my Java is (Or should be) correctly installed :

```
C:\elasticsearch-6.2.3\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

```
C:\elasticsearch-6.2.3\bin>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_211;
```

(Note : I also tried with the JAVA_HOME pointing to the jdk, without success)

```
C:\elasticsearch-6.2.3\bin>dir %JAVA_HOME%
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s’appelle Windows
 Le numéro de série du volume est 5AC7-0F6D

 Répertoire de C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_211

19/06/2019  11:46    <DIR>          .
19/06/2019  11:46    <DIR>          ..
19/06/2019  11:45    <DIR>          bin
19/06/2019  11:45             3 244 COPYRIGHT
19/06/2019  11:45    <DIR>          lib
19/06/2019  11:45                44 LICENSE
19/06/2019  11:45                46 README.txt
19/06/2019  11:45               426 release
19/06/2019  11:45           112 748 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
19/06/2019  11:45           149 725 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
19/06/2019  11:45               955 Welcome.html
               7 fichier(s)          267 188 octets
               4 Rép(s)  450 773 975 040 octets libres
```

Can someone please indicate to me what am I doing wrong here ? Is it an error from my own Java installation ? From elasticsearch ? Should I try to provide more details, and if yes, what kind of details ?

Thank you all in advance for your help !

Comment: It's ponting to JRE. Can you point it to the jdk instead? JAVA_HOME should point to the Jdk!

Comment: Just did so, pointing my JAVA_HOME to "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_211;". Nothing changed. I also tried pointing it to the other version of jdk that I tried to use (12.0.1), but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I ended up editing the elasticsearch.bat file, adding the following line :

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
```

Then, I relaunched elasticsearch.bat, and it worked ! I guess there was an issue for elasticsearch trying to get the environment variable.

I'm marking the question as answered, but if someone has more details on why is it behaving like this, I'll gladly take it !